Padding bytes when converting from unsigned char (1 byte) to unsigned short (2 byte)
When we are casting a unsigned char variable to a unsigned short variable, is it always guaranteed that the extra bytes are padded with zero? Is there any official source for this? It does work when I run a simple program on my machine.
Also, is this true when casting any lower byte type to a higher byte type?
#include<stdio.h>

typedef unsigned short    ub2;
typedef unsigned char  ub1;

// Function to check system endianness
void check_endianness() {
    unsigned int x = 0x12345678;
    char *c = (char *)&x;
            
    if (*c == 0x78) {
        printf("System is Little Endian\n\n");
    } else if (*c == 0x12) {
        printf("System is Big Endian\n\n");
    } else {
        printf("Unknown Endianness\n\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    // Step 1: Check the system's endianness
    check_endianness();
            
    // Initialize a ub1 pointer with a character array (string)
    ub1 *ptr = (ub1 *)"[1,2,";
    // Cast the first character (ub1) to ub2 and print in %x
    ub2 casted_value = (ub2) *ptr;
    printf("Original ub1 value: %x\n", *ptr);
    printf("Casted ub2 value: %x\n", casted_value);
}


Casting a smaller unsigned integer type to a larger unsigned integer type will zero-fill the high-order bits, thereby preserving the integer value.

"is this true when casting any lower byte type to a higher byte type?" -> not for signed integers, they get sign-extended.

Can you explain what do you mean by "casting"? The text I believe asks about the behaviof of (unsigned short)(unsigned char)5, but your code does nothing alike. Can you clarify? Is your code related to our question?

"is it always guaranteed that the extra bytes are padded with zero" - if it is not guaranteed then this is not casting but copying bytes.

Re "is it always guaranteed that the extra bytes are padded with zero?", Yes, but it's a "coincidental" result of how non-negative numbers are stored on all systems. It's a lot messier for signed types. On a two's complement system, -1 stored as FF could become -1 stored as FF FF. On a sign-magnitude system, -1 stored as 81 could become -1 stored as 80 01. etc

@julaine Not quite. "Sign extension" only applies on two's complement system.

@i486, Re "if it is not guaranteed then this is not casting but copying bytes.", That's not true. See the examples I gave for signed types. Other examples of cast that don't add zeroes: (double)1, (double)0.1f. So could (void*)p.

If both types are able to represent a value, then casting in either direction doesn't change that value.

@ikegami Cast may not add zeroes but it converts the whole value, not only part of it and it is not possible to leave upper byte of short variable with random value. In this case we talk about unsigned short variable, not for double.

This is specified in the C standard C17 6.3.1.3:

6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value
can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting
one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the
range of the new type.
Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is
implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

So conversions between integers are based on values contained in the variables. When going from a character type to a short, the value will always fit. And it must be preserved, meaning the rest of the short will remain unused.
This is not padding as such. The value 0x55 stored in a char will still be the value 0x55 when stored in a short. But since it has room for more, the short will be stored as the value 0x0055 in memory. Or rather, it will either get stored as 0x0055 (big endian) or 0x5500 (little endian).

It's possible that a char or an unsigned char might not fit in a short on weird architectures.

True. That said, the OP asked about unsigned char and unsigned short, and an unsigned char will always fit in an unsigned short.


When we are casting a unsigned char variable to a unsigned short variable, is it always guaranteed that the extra bytes are padded with zero?

Conversions operate on values, not bytes in memory: Casts performs conversions, which are operations in evaluating expressions. Like most operations, the C standard specifies them in terms of values. When bytes are written to memory (as with assignment) or read from memory (by using a variable for its value), then the bytes that represent them matter. But for a conversion by itself, converting an unsigned char with value 3 to unsigned short produces an unsigned short with value 3. The value is the same. The bytes are not specified and do not matter at this point.
When the unsigned short with value 3 is stored in memory, then it will be stored with bytes representing the value 3. This will include zeros in all the high bits.

Is there any official source for this?

The C 2018 standard specifies that casts perform conversion in its clause 6.5.4, paragraph 5. Details of the conversions are specified in paragraph 6 and clause 6.3. In particular, conversion from unsigned char to unsigned short is specified in 6.3.1.3. Since unsigned short can represent all the values of unsigned char, paragraph 1 applies:

When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.

How the unsigned short value 3 will be represented in memory is covered by clause 6.2.6.2, paragraph 1. This paragraph says that a pure binary representation is used. So the value 3 must have two one bits, representing 1•20 + 1•21 = 3, and all of its other value bits must be zero. (It might also have padding bits, which are additional bits in the storage unit used for unsigned short that do not participate in representing its value, but this is very rare these days.)
Note that the C standard does not specify how these bits are arranged in the memory storage unit used for unsigned short. They may not be in the same place in an unsigned short as they are in an unsigned char, even allowing for the fact there is an extra byte (assuming 8-bit unsigned char and 16-bit unsigned short). For example, it would conform to the C standard if all the bits in an unsigned char were in the order you expected but the bits in an unsigned short were in the order 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 15, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1. No C implementation actually does this, but, since you asked where this is specified, the answer is that nothing in the C standard requires that reading an unsigned byte with value 3 from memory and writing an unsigned short with value 3 to memory produces a low byte that is the same as the unsigned char and a high byte that is zero. How bits are arranged in each type will be specified (or at least taken as implicitly understood) in the documentation of each C implementation.
Also note this additional byte is not a padding byte. This byte in the unsigned short participates in representing its value. A padding byte is one that does not participate in representing the value of an object, such as bytes that are included inside structures so that the members of the structure will have the alignment they require.

Also, is this true when casting any lower byte type to a higher byte type?

The above applies for all conversions of integer types for which the source value is representable in the destination type. For conversions that change values or conversions between types other than integer types, there are additional rules.
